# Filter for two conditions in R and combine in one data table

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following table:

| totalAdjustments | accuracy |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 |

And would like to group it by totalAdjustments into two groups:

group1: totalAdjustments == 1 (named: oneAdjustment)

group2: totalAdjustments >= 2 (named: twoOrMoreAdjustments)

To get the following table:

| numberOfAdjustments | accuracy |
| --- | --- |
| oneAdjustment | 1 |
| twoOrMoreAdjustments | 2 |
| twoOrMoreAdjustments | 5 |
| oneAdjustment | 3 |

I currently import my csv with fread

> result <- fread("data.csv")

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### base R

You can use `ifelse` for that:

```r
ifelse(dat$totalAdjustments > 1, "twoOrMore", "one")
# [1] "one"       "twoOrMore" "twoOrMore" "one"      
dat$totalAdjustments <- ifelse(dat$totalAdjustments > 1, "twoOrMore", "one")
dat
#   totalAdjustments accuracy
# 1              one        1
# 2        twoOrMore        2
# 3        twoOrMore        5
# 4              one        3
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(totalAdjustments = if_else(totalAdjustments > 1, "twoOrMore", "one"))
#   totalAdjustments accuracy
# 1              one        1
# 2        twoOrMore        2
# 3        twoOrMore        5
# 4              one        3
```

---

If this is expanded to include another number, perhaps

> greater than 3 --> "tooMany"

then I would shift from a simple `ifelse` flow to `cut`:

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(totalAdjustments = cut(totalAdjustments, c(0, 1, 3, Inf), c("one", "twoOrMore", "tooMany")))
#   totalAdjustments accuracy
# 1              one        1
# 2        twoOrMore        2
# 3          tooMany        5
# 4              one        3
```

Note that `totalAdjustments` is now of class `factor` instead of `character`; the difference may be nothing, but often it can lead to unexpected results if you do not intend the class; in that case, wrap it with `as.character`, as in `= as.character(cut(...))`.